# Difference between a Flash SWF file and a Flash SWF compiled for use on iOS

Tags: ios, air, flash

SWF files compiled for the Flash & Air (desktop) can be easily de-compiled with off the shelf software.

However, SWF files compiled for iOS are different. The header is FWS, yet the data in the file wont de-compile in any de-compiler.

I am guessing that something happens during compilation for iOS. Does anyone what this is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you won't be able to do this.

A compiled AIR for iOS file is cross-compiled to Objective-C. Apple does not allow for virtualized languages in the App Store (which is how AIR for Desktop and Android work), so this was Adobe's solution. They take your AS3/Flex and translate it to Objective-C at compile-time so that at run-time, you are actually running native code.

So you would have to decompile the Objective-C first. Then you would have to reverse-engineer the entire AIR compiler and write a way to re-translate the decompiled Objective-C back to AS3.

For the record, any questions about decompiling binaries is generally frowned upon on SO.

Comment: Thats exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: May I also add that I am obfuscating my AS3 code with various off the shelf tools (and then viewing the swf in various de-compilers to check its working), but these only work for Android/Air/Flash. I was looking for a solution to protect my iOS version. But it now seems Apple/Adobe are doing it to some degree.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this sothink flashdecompiler?

And there is a Mac version that can help you out in it. [here](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/sothink-swf-decompiler-max/id413981732?mt=12)

Comment: Yes, I also tried AS3 Sourcerer, Trillix, Show My Code and JPEXS. They all report in some way the file is not valid, except JPEXS, but the source code is simply missing in that software.

Comment: It can also be noted a debug version of the app can be de-compiled in all these programs, but once I "build" the swf its no longer accessible.